# How can I set a DiscordColor in DiscordSharpPlus to a random RGB color?

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I have a Discord bot and I'm trying to make an embed with a random RGB color. When I try to use this command in discord, it simply returns nothing.

My code for this is:

```cs
DiscordEmbedBuilder Embed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
{
    Color = new DiscordColor(Rand.Next(0, 256), Rand.Next(0, 256), Rand.Next(0, 256))
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to make use of [this constructor](https://dsharpplus.github.io/api/DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordColor.html#DSharpPlus_Entities_DiscordColor__ctor_System_Byte_System_Byte_System_Byte_) which takes in three `byte` parameters.  However, when I tried your code in Visual Studio, it appears to try and use the constructor that makes uses of floats instead, and I get an exception:

[image: float overload]

Switching to this code, which explicitly casts the values to `byte` works:

```cs
Random rand = new Random();
DiscordEmbedBuilder Embed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
{
    Color = new DiscordColor((byte)rand.Next(0, 255), (byte)rand.Next(0, 255), (byte)rand.Next(0, 255))
};
```

[image: color!]

Also, you probably want `rand.Next(0, 255)` since [`byte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=net-6.0) only goes up to 255.